# In python3.9 type module NewType function allows creating derived with new data type

Tags: python, typing, newtype

Working with typing module of python, I am using NewType to create distinct types did following.

> UserId = NewType('UserId',int)

As per documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html if I use new data type UserId for any operation the output will be of original Type i.e. int. However doing this:

> total = UserId(0.3) + UserId(100)

> type(total) # the output is float. Why is this changing to float should it be int?

Even it allows to pass any other data type to UserId.

some_id = UserId('adfd')

## There is no error restricting to original type .i.e. int.

Further some_id datatype is set as str.

I was trying to rely on this for type checking and error out if data type doesn't match to original. Confused hence wanted to get opinion, is something wrong here?

Comment: As per documentation, "the Python runtime does not enforce function and variable type annotations". It's just a type *hint*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [documentation on `NewType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#newtype):

> Note that these checks are enforced only by the static type checker. At runtime, the statement `Derived = NewType('Derived', Base)` will make `Derived` a function that immediately returns whatever parameter you pass it. That means the expression `Derived(some_value)` does not create a new class or introduce any overhead beyond that of a regular function call.

So at runtime any `NewType` function is essentially just `lambda x: x`; it will not perform any `isinstance` checks. The purpose of using `NewType` is purely for type annotation. If you put your code in an IDE, or run it through type checkers such as [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/), a warning will be shown if you use it on an invalid type.

If you need runtime type-checks, you could do so with a simply function like this:

```
def UserId(x):
    if isinstance(x, int):
        return x
    raise TypeError(f"{x} is not an int")
```

Also, check out [pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/) if you need type-checking and validation for more complex structures.